# Big data online class

Tags: bigdata, self-study

Being an IT engineer, I am exploring the Big Data specialization and wishing to earn a certificate in that field to help me get a new job later.

I've been looking around and found these two specializations:

- [Data Science Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhu-data-science) from **John Hopkins University**
- [Big Data Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/big-data) from **UC San Diego**

I was hoping someone with experience in the field to advise on which to pick as it will be a big investment in time (months) and effort.

Any other suggestion out of the list is welcome.

Thank you!

PS: Let me know if I'm posting in the wrong section as this is a really genuine question!

Comment: I finally went with DS... Will provide a feedback when done for future "lost" people...